# MsSQL connection always return null in android

Tags: android, sql-server, jtds

i have this code:

```
public void update() {
        Log.i("Android", " MySQL Connect Example.");
        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            // test = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.class;
            String connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://my_ip:1433;instance=SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=Kukasauto_adatgyujto;user=***;password=***";
            String username = "***";
            String password = "***";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString, username, password);
            Log.w("Connection", "open");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet reset = stmt
                    .executeQuery("select * from dbo.Unit_Vocab;");
            // Print the data to the console
            while (reset.next()) {
                Log.w("Data:", reset.getString(1));
                // Log.w("Data",reset.getString(2));
            }
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("Error connection", "" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

it works with netbeans on pc, but not works on android.
i always got exception = null.

can you help me why?

Comment: how is this **My**Sql?

Comment: is it mysql or mssql ?

Comment: are you sure `my_ip` is accessible from the android device ? (hint: probably not)

Comment: also, don't just print the exception `message`.  print the full stacktrace.

Comment: it print just 'null' and it's mssql

Comment: Do you mean DriverManager.getConnection(connString, username, password); is returning null or that you are hitting your catch for your try?

Comment: i mean this catch (Exception e) {Log.d("Error connection", "" + e.getMessage());} prints: Error connection(14566): null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution:

replaced the

```
Log.w("Error connection", "" + e.getMessage());
```

to

```
Log.w("Error connection", "" + e.printStackTrace());
```

then it print the error: `strict mode...`